# populate an php array from another array according to parent and child values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which have 3 level

```
Array
 (
   [BIOCHEMISTRY] => Array
    (
        [BloodRoutine] => Array
            (
                [DifferentialCount] => Array
                    (
                        [itemId] => 552
                        [catId] => 2
                        [testId] => 1
                        [parent] => 0
                        [title] => FBS
                        [unit] => mg%
                        [amount] => 20
                        [catName] => BIOCHEMISTRY
                    )
               [ESR]=>2
               [PPR]=>4

            )
         [PCV]=>3

     )
  )
```

i need to populate an array if **testId** has value

```
 Array
 (
   [BIOCHEMISTRY] => Array
    (
        [BloodRoutine] => Array
            (
                [DifferentialCount] => Array
                    (
                        [itemId] => 552
                        [catId] => 2
                        [testId] => 1
                        [parent] => 0
                        [title] => FBS
                        [unit] => mg%
                        [amount] => 20
                        [catName] => BIOCHEMISTRY
                    )

            )

     )
  )
```

i need to populate an array if **ESR** has value, no value for any of the child for **DifferentialCount**

```
Array
 (
   [BIOCHEMISTRY] => Array
    (
        [BloodRoutine] => Array
            (

               [ESR]=>2

            )

     )
  )
```

i need to populate an array if **PCV** has value, no value for any of the child for **BloodRoutine**

```
Array
 (
   [BIOCHEMISTRY] => Array
    (

         [PCV]=>3

     )
  )
```

Please give me a dynamic function to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
foreach($input as $key1=>$level1) {
    if(is_array($level1)) {
        foreach($level1 as $key2=>$level2) {
            if(is_array($level2)) {
                foreach($level2 as $key3=>$level3) {
                    if(is_array($level3)) {
                        foreach($level3 as $key4=>$level4) {
                            if(isset($level4)) {
                                $output[$key1][$key2][$key3][$key4]=$level4;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if(isset($level3)) {
                            $output[$key1][$key2][$key3]=$level3;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if(isset($level2)) {
                    $output[$key1][$key2]=$level2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        if(isset($level1)) {
            $output[$key1]=$level1;
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($output);echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

use foreach function and loop through the array and using the $key in the foreach check 
if($key=='testid')
{//populate}
if($key=='ESR') and like wise. You need to do it in seperate foreach for the coding comfort.

Comment: can you write a function for the same